# Retrieving the sum of values falling within a specific timeframe

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some table like that

Time now: 16:00

```
User    counter    last_time

=====   =======    =========

user1      3        14:30

user2      2        15:40

user3      3        15:45
```

I want to show only the result what last_time is 1 hour less from now.

So considering my time now is 16:00 the result of sum of counter should be 5.

I update the counter and last_time during some user event.
Should I consider another column or can I do as I have?

Comment: ? None of these are 1 hour less than now.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is your table schema? What queries have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want to know how to get the counter sum of all rows within the last hour? If so, what exactly is your problem with that? Have you tried some query and got stuck? What is the problem you have not been able to solve?

Comment: Hey @ThorstenKettner. This is like sent mail counter per hour. I've tried something like this SELECT TIMEDIFF( $time, last_mail_time ) AS time FROM counter where last_mail_time <= '$time' and last_mail_time >= '$time'. I want to know how many emails (counter) I've sent last hour according last_mail_time. So user is the user who the email was sent. Everytime when user send email from php form, I update on his counter.

Comment: Hey @Strawberry. Considering now 16:00 and last hour 15:00 We have 2 results, right?

Comment: Those are *within* the last hour. Sticking the same value on each counter isn't terribly useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(counter INT NOT NULL
,last_time TIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'14:30:00'),
(2,'15:40:00'),
(4,'15:45:00');

SELECT SUM(counter) total 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE last_time >= CAST('16:00:00' AS TIME) - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     6 |
+-------+
```

For your scenario, you could replace `CAST...` with...

```
SELECT SUM(counter) total 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE last_time >= TIME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem now is how to reset the counter every hour. Maybe another column like first_hour?

Comment: There's a lot here that you can take away and adapt as the basis for a new question.